# Multiple instances of a variable (static, non-static)

Tags: c, static, scope

I came across this piece of C code:

```
main(){
static int i=0;
i++;

if(i<=5){
      int i = 3;
      printf(" %d",i);
      main();
    }
}
```

**1.** First, I expected this code to give a compilation error as there are multiple definitions of the variable `i`. But, it compiled and ran successfully and gave this output.

```
 3 3 3 3 3
```

**2.** Observing the output, *3* is printed exactly 5 times, which means the loop was counted from *0 to 5* thus implying that for the **if condition** , the first definition (static) of `i` was used.

**3** However, the value being printed is *3* which is the 2nd definition of `i`.

So the variable label `i` is referring to two different instances in memory. One is being used as the loop count, to do the increment, and the other is the value being printed.

The only way I can somehow explain this is:

1. `int i = 3` (the 2nd definition) is repeated in every recursive call. *That* instance of `i` is created when the function is called, and killed when the next recursive call is made. (Because of static scoping). `printf` uses *this* instance, as it is the latest definition(?)
2. When entering a new level of recursion, `i++` is being done. Since there is no other way to resolve this `i`, it uses the static "instance" of `i` , which  is still "alive" in the code as it was defined as  static.

However, I'm unable to exactly put a finger on  how this works..can anyone explain what's going on here, in the code and the memory?

How is the variable binding being done by the compiler here?

Comment: Read about [Variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Comment: You don't have a `while` loop...

Comment: @user3156863 Thanks for pointing that error out. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner scope wins.

Example:

```
int i = 1;
void foo() {
    int i = 2; // hides the global i

    {
        int i = 3; // hides local i
    }
}
```

This behavior is by design. What you can do is use different naming conventions for variable scopes:

- global/statics
- function arguments
- locals
- class/struct members

Some compilers will issue a warning if you hide a variable in the same function (e.g. function argument and regular local variable). So you the max warning level on your compiler.

Comment: Thanks, I always thought multiple definitions with the same identifier would give a compilation error. Tested your code with printf statements, after each definition and 1 2 3 was printed.

Comment: 2 definitions in the same scope is an error. A function arguemnt has the same scope as a local variable (`int i = 2` in the example)

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` of the *if statement* creates a new *block scope* and when you declare `i` in that scope you are *hiding* the `i` in the outer scope. The new scope does not start until `{` and thus the *if statement* is referring to the `i` in the outer scope.

Hiding is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.2.1` *Scopes of identifiers* paragraph *4* says (*emphasis mine*):

> [...]If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will be a
>   strict subset of the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; **the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope**.

Comment: @user3156863 that was a typo, I even said *if statement* in the beginning not sure why I typed *while* at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will always use the *most local version* of a variable when more than one variable of that name exists.

Outside the loop, the first `i` is the only one that exists, so it is the one that is checked. Then a new `i` is created, with value 3. At this point whenever you talk about `i` it will assume you mean the second one, since that's more local. When you exit the loop, the second `i` will go out of scope and be deleted and so if you start talking about `i` again it will be the first one.